# Load S3 data into Redshift using batch operations job

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-batch

I want to load data stored in S3 bucket into Redshift. I know it can be done manually. But, is it possible to use S3 batch operation job and schedule this task of loading S3 data into Redshift, on a regular interval?

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke a Lambda function from S3 Batch operations to load data into Redshift.

Check `Invoking AWS Lambda Functions` in Jeff Barr's below post

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/

Answer (score 1):

AWS Data Pipeline is a managed service that does exactly that. You can configure and schedule batch jobs that import data from S3 to Redshift.

Here's a tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-redshift.html

Comment: AWS Glue might also be an ideal candidate which can handle sourcing data into S3 as well. It is built for the  recurring ETL. But if you already have properly formatted data in S3, AWS Glue might be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Python script to do this by executing the `COPY` command to load data from S3 to Redshift. Use the `psycopg2` library in Python to run SQL commands on Redshift via Python code.